# How Can I Remove the SurveyMonkey Branding with the API on a paid account?

Tags: surveymonkey

I would like to use the REST API to disable the survey monkey branding in the footer of surveys on a paid plan, how can I do that?

Comment: It would be sweet if someone downvoting would explain why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to remove the footer from the Survey using the API.

This is a feature that should probably be added when creating/updating a Survey. You can watch the [public docs](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) on GitHub to be notified about changes. In the meantime this has to be set from the web interface.

Note that you can remove branding from [email invitation messages](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages) by setting `is_branding_enabled` to false.

Comment: Thank you for the info, any idea on when this might be released?

Comment: @PaulRedmond looks like either tomorrow or early next week

Comment: I was able to get this working, it is now possible by passing `"footer": false` to `POST /surveys` and `PATCH /surveys/{id}`